# How come this paper clip is " floating" on the subway floor?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

What's the physics behind the paper clip floating? Technically this was filmed on a subway floor in motion. So I'm guessing it has some Newtonian mechanics involved here, and maybe some other stuff I don't know? Please explain. Thank you.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qJoe8W-N98&feature=youtu.be

Sorry if this might not be the proper place to ask this question. I do not know much of physics.

Comment: The motor is probably under the paper clip and every time the power is applied, the paper clip aligns with the magnetic field.

Answer (score 2):

To give a real explanation one would have to repeat the experiment under controlled conditions, which is not simple with a moving metro cab.

Steel objects will move and be attached to magnetic fields: think of the magnetized scissors picking up fallen pins.

If it is an electric train, which a metro would be, there are strong currents converted for use   for the motion of the cab. Secondary currents could be induced in the metal body of the floor, or metal components beneath it,  variable depending on the strength and position of the cab under the power lines. Currents are accompanied by magnetic fields. This may show the behavior observed, as with pins and a nearing or further away scissors.
It may be a motor that goes on and off underneath the car, for some reason, braking or increasing/decreasing in energy .

All this is handwaving guess work. [Here is a link](http://www.jrtr.net/jrtr16/pdf/f48_technology.pdf) describing how electric trains are powered, and it will all depend on the exact system and the exact line and the exact geometry of the cab,